# Не работает роутинг Angular

Tags: angular

Смотрю на ютубе ролики по роутингу в Angular
Файл app-routing.module.ts, импорты опускаю

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '', component: MainPageComponent},
      {path: 'product/:id', component: ProductPageComponent},
      {path: 'cart', component: CartPageComponent}
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Далее там создают отдельный модуль admin.module.ts, в котором реализован еще один роутинг

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AdminLayoutComponent,
        LoginPageComponent,
        DashboardPageComponent,
        AddPageComponent,
        EditPageComponent,
        OrdersPageComponent,

    ],
    imports:[
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '', component: AdminLayoutComponent, children: [
                    {path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
                    {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent},
                    {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardPageComponent},
                    {path: 'add', component: AddPageComponent},
                    {path: 'orders', component: OrdersPageComponent},
                    {path: 'product/:id/edit', component: EditPageComponent},
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AdminModule{
    
}
```

По видосу, когда он заходит по адресу localhost:4200/admin, его перекидывает на страницу localhost:4200/admin/login
А меня выкидывает на localhost:4200

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, в Angular изменился синтаксис loadChildren, поэтому необходимо в app-routing.module.ts внести изменения:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '', component: MainPageComponent},
      {path: 'product/:id', component: ProductPageComponent},
      {path: 'cart', component: CartPageComponent}
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  }
];
```